# Can I use conditions in NGINX config with RTMP module?

Tags: nginx, debian, streaming, rtmp

I want to do different actions according to the stream key, like this:

```
application live {

            if(streamKey = 'stream_key_1') {
            #action1
            push rtmp://xxxxxx1
            }

            if(streamKey = 'stream_key_') {
            #action2
            push rtmp://xxxxxx2
            }

          }
```

when there is an incoming stream to the URL rtmp://my_server.com/live/stream_key_1 I want use action1 and if URL rtmp://my_server.com/live/stream_key_2 use action2

Is it even possible? Or is it done differently?

Thank you...

Comment: did you even found a solution